# accessing user documents folder on unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

is it possible to get the path to the current user documents folder on Unity3D using UnityScript? I am trying to access it mainly on desktop systems (Windows, Linux or OSX). On mobile systems, Application.persistentDataPath do the trick for me, but for desktop I would like to use the documents folder where the users can see and change the files easily.

Comment: Maybe this would be better posted at Game Devlopement

Comment: It's perfectly posted here, that's what the unity3d tag is for :) @chokito76 I'm not sure but I think it's not for security reasons.

Comment: check this: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/142323/accessing-the-local-computers-files.html

Comment: Thank you, Roberto, but this still doesn't give me the path to the user documents folder, just the way to access it after it was found... I am looking for something like Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments as in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx, unfortunately not exposed to javascript on Unity3D.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if Javascript has a way to get Windows special folders, but C# has [Environment.GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getfolderpath.aspx).

So one way of doing this is to create a C# script that will give you the My Documents path and put it in the *Standard Assets* folder. That way, javascript can call that script.

C# file

```
using System;
public class GetUserPathCSharp
{
    public static string GetUserPath()
    {
        return Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    }
}
```

Javascript file

```
#pragma strict
function Start () {
    var test = GetUserPathCSharp.GetUserPath();
    print("Path is " + test);
}
```

Note: Make sure that the C# script is inside the a folder called **Standard Assets**. [It's important](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/ScriptCompileOrderFolders.html).