# Is it possible to create a unity3d package using files from outside my project?

Tags: unity-game-engine, package

In most examples I see the paths to the files are relative ("Assets/Models/monster.fbx"), and this seems to work fine. But is it possible to have a file from outside my project included in a package? ("/Users/angrymonkey/Documents/dragon.fbx")

I'm doing this by code btw, not from the IDE. So I want to refer to files outside my current project from code.

Comment: If you want to use external assets for creating package, I assume you are doing it for development purposes - then why cannot you move the needed files inside your project? Other possible way is to use `"../../../specificFolder/neededFiles.fbx"`.

Comment: I need to use some compiled DLLs that have source code inside my project, so obviously when I move those DLLs with the same code that my project has I get compilation errors and I was trying to avoid that.

Comment: So the approach with `"../.."` doesn't fit your needs?

Comment: Thanks kreys, it's a workaround, I'd really prefer to use a cleaner way though if possible.

Comment: You can access `MyDocuments` folder on each platform, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545244/accessing-user-documents-folder-on-unity3d and http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/187013/creating-a-directory-in-my-documents.html

Comment: thanks for the answer, the problem doesn't seem to be in accessing those specific files, but actually including them in the package. I think that unity packages can only be created with files inside the /Assets folder of the project? I'm not sure but that seems to be the case ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54794/discussion-between-kreys-and-user2000950).